# calculate sum of digit in my zip code

Tags: c++

I want calculate sum of every digit in my zip code so I wrote implementation function like that but, it shows "0" as answers, then I realize it should be call first, I add correctionDigitOf() in to constructor "Zipcode::Zipcode" then My zipcode are all "0' after I do this so please help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Zipcode
{
public:
    Zipcode();

    void createZipcode();
    int getZipcode();
    int extract(int location);
    int getCoreectionDigit();
    void correctionDigitOf();

private:
    int zipcode;
    int correctionDigit;
};

Zipcode::Zipcode()
{
    zipcode = 0;
    correctionDigit = 0;
    createZipcode();
}

void Zipcode::createZipcode()
{
    zipcode = 10000 + rand() % 99999;
}

int Zipcode::getZipcode()
{
    return zipcode;
}

int Zipcode::extract(int location)
{
    int i = 1;
    while (i<location)
    {

        i++;
        zipcode /= 10;
    }

    return zipcode % 10;
}

void Zipcode::correctionDigitOf()
{
    correctionDigit = extract(1) + extract(2) + extract(3) + extract(4) + extract(5);
}

int Zipcode::getCoreectionDigit()
{

    return correctionDigit;
}

int main()
{
    const int num = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i<num; i++)
    {

        Zipcode zip;
        cout << zip.getZipcode()
            << ' '
            << zip.getCoreectionDigit()
            << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You generate zip codes that have up to 6 digits, not 5.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Zipcode::extract` changes the value of `zipcode`, which can't possibly be what you want.